# differenciate the date from the meta data of user meta table

Tags: php, wordpress

I found the last login date from the user meta table by the code bellow.

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  $time = get_user_meta($current_user,"last_login", true);
  echo $time;
```

i got the output like written bellow.

```
2012-12-26 10:00:40
```

Now i want to differentiate the date and only print the date  2012-12-26. How can i print the date only by php. There is any in php or in wordpress to get the date only from the meta table in database.Please help me in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may solve your prb:

```
$date = new DateTime('2012-12-26 10:00:40');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <?php $date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2012-12-26 10:00:40')); 
  echo $date
 ?>
```

**OR**

```
<?php $date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($time)); 
  echo $date
 ?>
```